# How to swap alternate key value pairs in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary `dict1={ "K1":"V1","V2":"K2","K3":"V3","V4":"K4","K5":"V5"}`. I want to swap key/value pairs of alternate items in python. The output should be like: `{ "K1":"V1","K2":"V2","K3":"V3","K4":"V4","K5":"V5"}`

I am trying the following code.

```
def solution(dict1):
    new_dict={}
    for i in range(1,len(dict1)+1):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            for key, value in dict1.items():
                new_dict[value] = [key]
        else:
            continue
        return new_dict

dict1={ "K1":"V1","V2":"K2","K3":"V3","V4":"K4","K5":"V5"}
c=solution(dict1)
print(c)
```

But this code is alternating all the elements in dictionary.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have two nested loops here. Every time `i % 2 == 0` you copy every swapped key/value from `dict1` to `new_dict`. You also never copy any without swapping them.

Comment: @Kemp i%2==0 only when even value at odd it won't be true so I am swapping at only even value Any suggestions

Comment: When `i` is odd you copy *every* value from `dict` to `new_dict` (and you do this every time `i` is odd). When `i` is even you do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
dict1 = {"K1": "V1", "V2": "K2", "K3": "V3", "V4": "K4", "K5": "V5"}


def solution(d):
    rd = {}
    for i, (k, v) in enumerate(d.items()):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            rd[v] = k
        else:
            rd[k] = v
    return rd


print(solution(dict1))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried like below:

```
def solution(dict1):
    new_dict={}
    for key in dict1:
        if 'K' in key:
            new_dict[key]=dict1[key]
        else:
            new_dict[dict1[key]] = key
    return new_dict
```

And the output was:

```
{'K1': 'V1', 'K2': 'V2', 'K3': 'V3', 'K4': 'V4', 'K5': 'V5'}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
k = 0
dict2 = {}

for key, value in dict1.items():
    if k % 2 != 0:
        dict2[value] = key
    else:
        dict2[key] = value
    k = k+1
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the line
`for key, value in dict1.items(): new_dict[value] = [key]`
You already have an iterator, so you are iterating through the entire list when `i` is even. You need only swap the one. I would do something like this:

```
i = 0

for key in dict1:
    i += 1
    if i%2 == 0:
        new_dict[dict1[key]] = key
    else:
        new_dict[key] = dict1[key]
```

Here, the iterator `i` is only checking if it is even or odd, but it is not actually iterating through the dict object.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create a new copy of dictionary as directly adding / removing key-value pairs from a dictionary while iterating it will cause it's size to change, thus causing runtime error: `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`. Use the below code to avoid it:

```
dict1={ "K1":"V1","V2":"K2","K3":"V3","V4":"K4","K5":"V5"}
dict2 = {}
i = 0;
for key in dict1:
    if i%2 == 1:
        x = dict1[key]
        dict2[x] = key
    elif i%1 == 0:
        dict2[key] = dict1[key]
    i = i+1    

print(dict2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dictionary comprehension.

```py
dict1 = {"K1": "V1", "V2": "K2", "K3": "V3", "V4": "K4", "K5": "V5"}

dict2 = {
    k if idx % 2 == 0 else v: v if idx % 2 == 0 else k
    for idx, (k, v) in enumerate(dict1.items())
}
```